# Hibernate inserts null even when field is not null in the object being saved

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am facing a weird issue where even though all fields are set in the java object, when I save the object hibernate tries to insert null values in the fields.

When I further debugged, I saw that while merging the new entity at [this](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/type/EntityType.java#L294) line hibernate generates an empty object and sets to the target instead of setting given entity to the target. This results in insert query with null values.

Am I missing some configuration here? Below are the example entities having associations similar to my case.

```
class Vehicle {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private VehicleType vehicleType;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="vehicle", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Car car;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="vehicle", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Truck truck;
}

class Car {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "vehicle_id")
    private Vehicle vehicle;

    ...
}

class Truck {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "vehicle_id")
    private Vehicle vehicle;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Please show a code where you create entities , set fields and save it

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, in my case I have an application with:

```
 public class Claim extends BaseEntity<Integer> implements Serializable {
      
      @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
      @JoinColumn(name = "claimdetailsid", referencedColumnName = "id")
      private ClaimDetails claimDetails;
    
      @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
      @JoinColumn(name = "beneficiaryid", referencedColumnName = "id")
      private Beneficiary beneficiary;

      ....
}
```

When I saved the Claim entity, the Claim and ClaimDetails objects were inserted correctly. The other entities had all the fields null, except the id and the creation date.

I tried changing CascadeType.PERSIST to CascadeType.ALL, that solved my insert problem.

But the delete cascade doesn't work now.

Comment: I have modify `cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE }`, they solved probems with null and the delete cascade.